# Javascript shorthand for true or false in function

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Is there a shorthand way of doing this so that the outcome is always true or false?

```js
function trueFalse() {
  if( a == 1 ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Something like return true:false; and no need for the else section?

Thanks.

Comment: `a == 1` is already a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be:

```
function trueFalse(){
  return a === 1;
}
```

Also, as much as possible, use strict comparison.

Comment: Thank you. What's the downside of not using a strict comparison?

Comment: @martin: If the two things you're comparing are of the same type, there is no downside at all. But if they're different types, using `===` will guarantee that they're not equal. E.g., `"1" == 1` is `true` but `"1" === 1` is false. Using `==` means that the JavaScript engine will do type coercion. The rules of type coercion in JavaScript are *complex*, and so some people believe you should always use `===`. Nothing is free, though: If you always use `===`, then on those occasions when you want type coercion, you have to do it explicitly. (But that's part of the point.)

Comment: Thanks, mostly understood. I've only ever used ==. As far as I can tell it's not causing any issues. I wonder if I should just replace them all with ===, and similarly !== for != ?

Comment: @martin: If you do, you'll probably introduce issues into existing code, as you're probably relying on type coercion somewhere. Doing that isn't necessarily a bad thing, just be aware that it may happen and flag up places you need to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

(a few years after OP question but this would now also work)

ES6 shorthand would allow you to use a conditional operator:

`const trueFalse = a === 1 ? true : false`

Or even shorter but a bit less readable:

`const trueFalse = a === 1`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator